# cannot stat './nasm.1': No such file or directory

Tags: nasm

while building nasm i am getting this error

Installing with make install...

```
========================= Installation results ===========================
/usr/bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install -c nasm ndisasm /usr/local/bin/
/usr/bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/share/man/man1
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./nasm.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/nasm.1
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat './nasm.1': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:385: install] Error 1

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.
```

I am trying to build nasm

Comment: **−1**: I downvoted this question because a quick look at the NASM project’s issue tracking system “Bugzilla” would have shown results: [Bugzilla.NASM.us/buglist.cgi query for `cannot stat`](https://bugzilla.nasm.us/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=cannot%20stat). There are multiple _open_ issues.